# PrintWriter println(String s) method: \r\n not supported?

Tags: java, printwriter, println

I'm creating a multithread chat client server application.
In the server connection I use PrintWriter println(String s) method to write the response to the client.

```
PrintWriter out;
String msg = in.readLine();
String response = "";
if (msg.startsWith("nick: ") {
    response = protocol.authenticate(msg); //returns a String that says "welcome " + nick
    //if there are messages pending for the author who logged in add them to the response String
         response+="\r\n"+textmsg;
} else { ... }
out.println(response);
```

When I run the client, who uses the BufferedReader readLine() method to read from the server, I get the welcome message but not the pending message for the client, but If I use

```
response+=textmsg;
```

it works, so I assume it's because I'm using \r\n but I still need to print a new line between those two messages. What should I do?

**Edit** after accepting the answer: In the end I chose to use OutputStream and InputStream so I can send every kind of string I want, even with \r\n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either call `println` once for each line of output (so twice) or use only `\n`, without the `\r`. That's Java's standard newline char and `\r\n` is a Windows-specific end-of-line sequence. Of course, at the client end you now have to call `readLine` twice as well. There is no way to call `readLine` once and get two lines. If you need a custom delimiter, then you must use something else, not `\n`.

Comment: Looks like it works, thanks. If I use only \n will the new line be displayed in the same way in every os?

Comment: Yes, Java should handle that. But when an over-the-wire protocol is in question, the encoding shouldn't be platform-specific in the first place. it would only concern reading/writing files.

Answer (score -1):

Use println with PrintWriter, for the \n.